# Google fonts developer API request syntax? How to get specific info?

Tags: rest, fonts, httprequest

I am trying to figure out the possibilities with the Goolge Fonts developer API and I must admit that I find the documentation a bit thin.

I am not refering to the Google fonts API where your request fonts like this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
```

but the developer API where you request font **info** like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=api_key
```

Given you use a valid API key in the above request, you get a large JSON object with info about all the Google fonts. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#Details), you can sort the list using five different methods. Using the method of popularity, the syntax is as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=popularity
```

It took me a while to figure out how to combine the sorting request with the api_key request, but after consulting this [tutorial](http://rest.elkstein.org/) about REST it turns out that you can separate parameters with an ampersand. So to get a sorted list you would type the request like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=api_key&sort=popularity
```

But this can't be all you can do with the Google foont developer API? What if I wanted data for just a few fonts or a list of all the monospace fonts. What would be the syntaxes for such requests? Thanks.

Comment: reading the docs, that's exactly the only thing it does? Just grab the full list, throw out what you don't need, and as sensible practice, don't do that client side, but do it server-side, because the google offering isn't going to change every minute, hour, or even day. You just ask for it once, parse the result, throw out what you don't need, do what you need to do as part of your deployment bootstrap, done. Individual users should never need to invoke this functionality as part of normal use.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is not that big of a deal after all. Good idea to just grab the full list once in a while. But seriously, if this is all it takes to call something an API, I am adding API developer to my resume pronto. It's simple: Just provide a link to some file and have people decode it on their end. Come to think of it, I have developed a lot of APIs in my time.

Comment: you probably have. Even a single function that gives access in some form to a data system is an API, as long as it's versioned, stable and well-documented. Those last two are fairly essential.